# Find how many yields and their names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, layout, yield

Is there a way in Rails to find out how many yields have been defined in a layout along with their corresponding names?

Comment: Not a way in Rails, but what Steve answered will work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
grep -c yield < layout.html.erb
```

That should get you the count you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

or `ack "yield" app/views/layouts/`. See [Ack - Better thanGrep](http://betterthangrep.com/)